# How to Make Large Matrix Multiply

Tags: glsl

I'm trying to make an GLSL shader that multiplies a 90x10 matrix with an 10x1 one. The 90x1 result corresponds to the xyz values of 30 vertices. The first large matrix is only loaded at startup. The other matrix, on the other hand, can change at each render.

How could this be done? I'm guessing the first matrix could be stored as a texture, but I have no idea what to do with the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the second matrix as a uniform array of floats.

```
uniform float vec10[10];
```

and perform the multiplication element by element.

Note that if that's too slow, you can try packing your large texture in such a way that you can read 4 elements with a single texelfetch.

If you want to see the syntax for binding uniform arrays, consult http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL) .

Note, that its also completely legal to store this second matrix in texture as well; I'm just not sure of the performance impact of doing so as opposed to sending as a uniform. But get it working first, profile and optimize later.